# Using a custom field converter in a where clause in JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, sql, orm, jooq

I'm trying to do a select from where in JOOQ using this syntax:

```
public final org.jooq.TableField<MyType, java.lang.String> DATE = createField("date", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.VARCHAR.length(8), this);
Cursor<MyRecord> cursor =
            create.selectFrom(MYTABLE)
            .where( MYTABLE.DATE_STRING_COLUMN.greaterOrEqual( ??? ) )
            .fetchLazy();
```

The code generator knows about this column but sees it as a String. MyType is the type of MyRecord.

The problem that I have is that the Database stores a String for the data that I need to convert to java.sql.date.
I want to call a custom converter in the where clause to convert the native Date type which is a string like "2014-03-24" to a java.sql.Date.
The reason that this wasn't working was that there was no type conversion between String and Java.sql.Date, so you'd get a type mis-match.

The problem is that I can't seem to find the right type to put in the conditional (where I have the three question marks).
I have a custom field converter that implements that the convert() method that takes a record and returns a java.sql.Date object, but I can't seem to get the right type to put there. I'm getting around it using a raw SQL String for now, it looks like this: `str_to_date(date, '%m-%d-%y') >= now()`
Does anyone how I can invoke the custom field converter inside of the where clause?

Comment: Could you please post the declaration of `MYTABLE.DATE_STRING_COLUMN`? Did you configure the jOOQ code generator to use your converter for that column? Also, I think your example will need a little more explanation. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Lukas Edited the question as you suggested. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not sure if I can make sense of your question... Are `DATE` and `DATE_STRING_COLUMN` the same? Are `MyType` and `MyRecord` the same? What keeps you from actually storing a SQL `DATE` in your database (from what I understand, you're storing a `VARCHAR`) ?

Comment: @LukasEder I've updated the question. Thanks again for bearing with me on this. It seems like what I'm trying to do might not be possible. I've fallen back on just using a Native SQL String in the where clause for now, but any better suggestion would help.

Comment: Could you maybe show that native SQL in your where clause? Maybe that helps understand your use-case

Comment: No problem, added that as well.